# SetCreationTime not working on files in a Shared Folder

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, file-io, administration

I'm using the File.SetCreationTime() method to update the creation time of files. It works on files in local folders, but for some reason it doesn't work on a shared network folder. I can create, delete, rename files using the same application, but this method just refuses to work.
I've read the method description on MSDN, and it says that an UnauthorizedAccessException is raised, when the caller doesn't have the proper permissions. However, I don't get any kind of exception.
What could be the cause of this behavior? Is there a workaround, or an alternative way of setting the creation time of a file?

Here's the relevant code snippet:

```
try
{
   DateTime dt = fi.CreationTime; //fi is a FileInfo of the given file
   DateTime newdt = new DateTime(dt.Year, dt.Month, dt.Day, dt.Hour, dt.Minute, dt.Second, position);
   _log.DebugFormat("Setting the CreationTime attribute to {0} ticks...", newdt.Ticks);
   fi.CreationTime = newdt;
   File.SetCreationTime(filePath, newdt);
   _log.DebugFormat("CreationTime check: {0}", File.GetCreationTime(filePath).Ticks);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
   _log.DebugFormat("Error details: {0}", ex.ToString());
}
```

According to the debug log output, the application attempts to set the new datetime. The "CreationTime check:" will however still show the 'old' datetime value.

Comment: I am seeing the same issue with a local directory exposed in IIS as a virtual directory.  Changing permissions doesn't seem to help...

Comment: @iisystems Thanks for confirming that this is issue exists elsewhere as well. I had to do a workaround and use the "Last Modified Date" instead of the "Creation Date". I wonder if it's an intended behaviour, or an actual bug.